# React Conditional Render with object mapping and extra components

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I want to do conditional rendering with mapping Object and component together

For example

```
return(
    fixed? 
      Object.values(data).map((content, index)=>(
       <SomeObject1/> 
      )
      // mapping and extra components
       <ExtraThing1/>
       <ExtraThing2/>
      :

        Object.values(data).map((content, index)=>(
       <SomeObject2/> 
      )
       <ExtraThing3/>
       <ExtraThing4/>

)
```

Is there way to do this in one return?

Comment: isn't the code you shared above a single return with the conditional rendering? You can move the component to be conditionally rendered after `SomeObject` and avoid rewriting the same components

Comment: @van I made wrong example. It would be different component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Yoshi's answer is technically correct, but doesn't quite match OP's code. The React `Fragment` (`<></>`) grouping is on each branch of the ternary operator, each group consisting of the mapped components and some extra components. For each returned value a single React node should be returned.

```
return fixed ? (
  <>
    {Object.values(data).map((content, index) => (
      <SomeObject1 />
    ))}
    // mapping and extra components
    <ExtraThing1 />
    <ExtraThing2 />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    {Object.values(data).map((content, index) => (
      <SomeObject2 />
    ))}
    <ExtraThing3 />
    <ExtraThing4 />
  </>
);
```